# stuck on a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

let be the differential equation

$ x^{2} y''(x)+ y(x)(a^{2}+k^{2} _{n})=0 $

the boundary conditions are $ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx |y(x)|^{2} < \infty $ and $ y(0) $ must be finite (regular solutions near the origin )

here $ a^{2} >0 $ and $ k^{2} _{n}>0 $ these $ k_{n} $ are a discrete set of eigenvalues

my question is how can i transform my differential equation into a more well-known differential equation so i can get the eigenvalues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an homogeneous [Euler equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html). Its solution is $y(x)=C_1x^{r_1}+C_2x^{r_2}$ where $r_1,r_2$ are the solutions of the indicial equation
$$
r(r-1)+a^2+k_n^2=0.
$$
None of these solutions is square integrable on $(0,\infty)$ unless $C_1=C_2=0$.

Comment: OK, thanks.. :)